# Locating a button causes str object not callable in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Good afternoon,

I think i have a okay grasp on selenium so far and what i would like to do is locate the ontrust cookie accept button on https://coinmarketcap.com/, Through reading i have learnt that you should wait till the element is visible on the page since some might not have been loaded at the time, so what i've tried to do is

```
def accept_cookies(self) -> None:
        accept_cookie_button = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.CSS_SELECTOR('button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler')))
        accept_cookie_button.click()
```

I've also tried it by ID and ran into the same issue. So unsure where to go at the moment any light to be shed would be welcomed

Forgot the error message:

```
File "Data-collection-pipeline\scraper.py", line 17, in accept_cookies
    accept_cookie_button = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.CSS_SELECTOR('button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler')))    
                                                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: It should be `By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler'`, not `By.CSS_SELECTOR('button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler')`

Comment: Thank you Gordon i'm not sure how the heck i did that mistake, did not read the documentation properly